# C# Recursive method that receives an integer n and prints all the integers from n to 0 in ascending order

Tags: c#, recursion

I tried to make a recursive method for printing integer n to 0 in ascending order but apparently it is not correctly written as a recursive method.

```
private static int MyAscRec(int n)
     {
        int counter = 0;
         while(counter <= n)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(counter);
               counter++;
            }
            return counter;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = MyAscRec(20);         
        }
```

Comment: recursion involves a method calling itself. This does not.  I suggest looking at your textbook again.

Comment: A recursive (re-entrant) method is a method that during the course of its processing, may call itself. This method is not written to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to print the numbers, the function can be as simple as:

```
private static void MyAscRec(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) return;     // End of recursion
    MyAscRec(n - 1);       // Recursive call first so you get the ascending order
    Console.WriteLine(n);  
}
```

If you wanted a descending order you would simply change the order of the `Console.WriteLine(n);` and the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `MyAscRec()` doesn't need to be `int`. It can instead be `void`. Here's a code to do what you are trying to:

```
private static void MyAscRec(int n){
    if(n==0)
    Console.Write(n+" ");
    else{
        MyAscRec(n-1);
        Console.Write(n+" ");
    }
}
```